# Error to use Bundle FOSJsRoutingBundle in symfony2

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to use the bundle FOSJsRoutingBundle with symfony and angularjs but the console log give me a error.

```
ReferenceError: goog is not defined
goog.provide('fos.Router');


ReferenceError: fos is not defined
..._crear":{"tokens":[["text","\/"]],"defaults":[],"requirements":[],"hosttokens":[...
```

anybody know why show this error?

Comment: can you show us your AppKernel, app/config/routing.yml files

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue when I was trying to concat all javascript files for production. The simple reason was, that I included the file

`./vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle/Resources/js/router.js`

instead of

`./vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle/Resources/public/js/router.js`.

Hope this helps.